# Code First Entity / MVC4 - why aren't my models hydrated?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, entity, code-first

I can not figure out what I'm doing wrong here.  New to MVC and new to Entity, so I know that's holding me back.  Any time I call up AuthUser, AuthRole is always nothing, so I end up doing something like:

```
authuser.AuthRole = db.AuthRoleSet.Find(2) 'AuthRoleID of 2 = User
```

This just feels clunky to me.  How do I get my property to actually get the role with the user?

Here's my class structure:
    Public Class AuthUser
        'Class Globals
        Dim db As New AuthUserContext

```
    'Properties
    Public Property AuthUserID() As Integer

    <Required()> _
    <Display(Name:="User Name")> _
    <DomainUserValidation()> _
    Public Property UserName() As String

    <Display(Name:="Current Role")> _
    Public Property AuthRole As AuthRole

End Class

Public Class AuthRole
    Public Property AuthRoleID() As Integer

    <Required()> _
    <Display(Name:="Role Name")> _
    Public Property RoleName() As String

    <Required()> _
    <Display(Name:="Is Administrator")> _
    Public Property isAdministrator() As Boolean

    <Required()> _
    <Display(Name:="Is Active")> _
    Public Property isActive() As Boolean

    <Required()> _
    Public Property AuthUser As ICollection(Of AuthUser)

End Class

Public Class AuthUserContext
    Inherits DbContext
    Public Property AuthUserSet() As DbSet(Of AuthUser)
    Public Property AuthRoleSet() As DbSet(Of AuthRole)
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options (sorry c# syntax):

1 - Lazy load `AuthRole` when you need it - for this, your `AuthRole` property needs to be declared as `virtual`

```
public virtual AuthRole {get;set;}
```

Now, when/if you try to access `AuthRole`, EF will get it from database.
For this to work you need to have `DbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadEnabled = true`

Another alternative is to eager load it by using a query like this:

```
var myUserWithRole = myContext.AuthUsers.Include("AuthRole").FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id == userId);
```

This will get the user and the role from the database.